# Android ArrayAdapter increasing cached views to improve performance

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, convertview

So I have a listview with an image and some text hooked by a custom array adapter. The problem I am facing is that the image is still loading a little bit too slow for my liking. I've watched the google tech talk and attempted to optimize my list by resusing the view by the convertView (if it's null then inflate, if not, resuse). I've also spawned AsyncTasks to load the bitmap with BitmapFactory.Options inSampleSize set to a power of 2, since the image is relatively small. I've also used the ViewHolder pattern to reduce findViewById calls.

However, even with this, when I scroll through my list, it is very noticeable how the convertViews are being reused because the image constantly gets updated as I scroll up and down.

What I noticed in the stock Android photo gallery is, with the hundreds of photos that I have, when I scroll through quickly, the photos initially load slowly, but then get cached. The amount cached is MUCH more than what the screen is capable of showing, so as I scroll, initially the photos load seamlessly until I scroll pass the amount of photos cached, and then the reload of photos is noticeable again.

Is there a way to do this with the ArrayAdapter? Basically, store more than the 9 views within my listview (What my screen is capable of showing) for the purposes of when a user scrolls down quickly, the user would have to scroll down a lot before the convertView is reused and thus the noticeable image reloads?

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the images in the background, using multiple parallel threads.

For example: [Sending Operations to Multiple Threads](http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/index.html); the sample app downloads thumbnails from the Picasa Featured Photos RSS feed. Hope this helps.